# How to change a state by adding CSS classes in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to rotate a simple icon in React. By clicking on a button it should rotate the other way.
I am still learning react. In javascript it is somewhat easier. You just hook it to a event listener. But not sure how to do it in react.

```css
@keyframes infinite-rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotate {
  animation: infinite-rotate 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```
function RotateIcon() {
return (
<div>
<Icon className="rotate" />
<button>Rotate me</button>
)
}

export default RotateIcon
```

Comment: Your state can control what `className` an element has. In this case, you might do something like `className={someState ? "rotate" : undefined}`

Comment: You didn't even add a state variable to your component?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I still don't know the syntax to be comfortable with it. I just code and practice till it makes sense based on my projects. Still appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Final Output:

[image]

Use the state for tracking whether to rotate the element or not, based on that assign the class name, and then after that apply the styles in the CSS file.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const Icon = ({ className }) => {
  return <div className={className} />;
};

function RotateIcon() {
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon
        className={
          rotate % 3 == 1
            ? "rotate-clk icon"
            : rotate % 3 == 2
            ? "rotate-ant icon"
            : "icon"
        }
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setRotate(rotate + 1);
        }}
      >
        {rotate % 3 == 1
          ? "rotate-anticlowise"
          : rotate % 3 == 2
          ? "stop"
          : "rotate-clockwise"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RotateIcon;
```

CSS:

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
@keyframes infinite-rotate-clk {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes infinite-rotate-ant {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.rotate-clk {
  animation: infinite-rotate-clk 2s linear infinite;
}

.rotate-ant {
  animation: infinite-rotate-ant 2s linear infinite;
}


.icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #b0f500 25%,
    #000000 25%,
    #000000 50%,
    #b0f500 50%,
    #b0f500 75%,
    #000000 75%,
    #000000 100%
  );
  background-size: 56.57px 56.57px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Working app demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wjqkfj?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thanks man. I learn by doing. Still new to the React use state syntax. How can I further control the direction of the rotating icon? So onClick to be changed in other direction. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: so you want to have the functionality of clockwise and anticlockwise direction? wait, will update the code.

Comment: updated the code in the given demo example app.

Comment: Thank you so much.Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `useref` hook for accessing the component , or you can simply access it with classes or id , like in the js,
then you can add or remove classes with `onClick`

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. But generally I should use states, or? Just to remove myself a bit from VanillaJS.

Comment: states are used for items on screen they need to change, like values , if you have something thta's something related to css manipulation that you used to do with query selector, in that case you can use the useref hook, for better understanding you can look into the difference between states and refs

Comment: Really nice input. Thank you! I will look it more in detail.